# Clone PHP form and append to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to attach a long form (from external page) to a dynamically created Div using jQuery.

So Far i got this as jQuery:

```
<script>
    $('.add-player').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var id = $("#menuPlayers.nav-tabs li[role='presentation']").length+1;  with role = presentation
        var tabId = 'player_' + id;
        $(this).closest('li').before('<li role="presentation"><a href="#player_' + id + '" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px;">' + id + '</a></li>');
        $('.tab-content').append('<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '">' + $("#cloneThisDiv").clone().appendTo("#" + tabId) + '</div>');
        $('#menuPlayers.nav-tabs li:nth(' + id + ') a').click();
    });
</script>
```

And as HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<legend> 
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="menuPlayers">
  <li>Insert Players &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#player_1" aria-controls="player_1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#player_2" aria-controls="player_2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" ><a href="#player_3" aria-controls="player_3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab>3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="add-player"> <b> + </b> </a></li>
  </ul>
</legend>

<div class="tab-content">

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="player_1">
    ... PHP LONG FORM that i want to clone to the new div created with jQuery...
</div>

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="player_2">
 Tab2
</div>

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="player_3">
 Tab 3  
</div>

</div>
```

But i can't reach what i am looking for...
Using this line `$("#cloneThisDiv").clone().appendTo("#" + tabId)` it returns **[object Object]** when new tab is created.
Is there another way i can clone my form, everytime user want to add a new player, without using the whole code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to use `.html()` instead of using `.clone().appendTo(`

```js
$('.add-player').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var id = $("#menuPlayers.nav-tabs li[role='presentation']").length+1;  //with role = presentation
    var tabId = 'player_' + id;
    $(this).closest('li').before('<li role="presentation"><a href="#player_' + id + '" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px;">' + id + '</a></li>');
    $('.tab-content').append('<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '">' + $("#player_1").html() + '</div>');
    $('#'+tabId).find('.form').find('h3').text(tabId);
    $('#menuPlayers.nav-tabs li:eq(' + id + ') a').click();
});
$('#menuPlayers').on('click' , 'li a:not(.add-player)',function(){
  $('.tab-pane').hide();
  $($(this).attr('href')).show();
}).find('a[href="#player_1"]').click();
```

```css
.form{
  background : #005eff;
  padding : 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<legend> 
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="menuPlayers">
  <li>Insert Players &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#player_1" aria-controls="player_1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#player_2" aria-controls="player_2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" ><a href="#player_3" aria-controls="player_3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="add-player"> <b> + </b> </a></li>
  </ul>
</legend>

<div class="tab-content">

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="player_1">
      <form class="form">
        <h3>Player_1</h3>
        <input type="text" /><br/>
        <input type="text" /><br/>
        <textarea></textarea>
      </form>
  </div>

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="player_2">
   Tab2
  </div>

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="player_3">
   Tab 3  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mohamed, that actually Worked!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried like this:

```
var form = $("#cloneThisDiv").clone();
$("#"+tabId).append(form);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `appendTo` method returns a `domNode` so you can't use it as a string inside the `append` method.

Try this code:

```
<script>
$('.add-player').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var id = $("#menuPlayers.nav-tabs li[role='presentation']").length+1;  with role = presentation
    var tabId = 'player_' + id;
    $(this).closest('li').before('<li role="presentation"><a href="#player_' + id + '" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px;">' + id + '</a></li>');
    var newPlayerTab = $('.tab-content').append('<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '"></div>');
    $("#cloneThisDiv").clone().appendTo($(newPlayerTab));

    $('#menuPlayers.nav-tabs li:nth(' + id + ') a').click();
});
```